Why can't I make a get-request with aiohttp: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)?
Why do I see an error

Error while making request to
https://data.similarweb.com/api/v1/data?domain=httpbin.org: Expecting
value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

with aiohttp while requests.get returns the correct json?
import aiohttp
import asyncio
import nest_asyncio

nest_asyncio.apply()

async def fetch(session, url):
    try:
        async with session.get(url, headers=headers) as response:
            return await response.json(content_type=None)
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error while making request to {url}: {str(e)}")

async def fetch_all(urls):
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        tasks = []
        for url in urls:
            tasks.append(fetch(session, url))
        responses = await asyncio.gather(*tasks, return_exceptions=True)
        return responses

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/122.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
}

urls = ['https://data.similarweb.com/api/v1/data?domain=' + 'httpbin.org']

responses = asyncio.run(fetch_all(urls))

httpbin.org/headers returns exactly the same headers with the only difference in X-Amzn-Trace-Id value.

Could also be related to query parameters. For something like that, you should probably use the params argument to specify the query parameters. If you need to use the full URL, then you may need them pre-encoded. https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/client_quickstart.html#passing-parameters-in-urls

The error doesn't happen while making the request (as your code incorrectly assumes) but after the request has finished. You should inspect the response object instead of assuming that everything went well and handling the payload. For example, print out the response status like this:
    try:
         async with session.get(url, headers=headers) as response:
             print(response.status, response.reason)
             return await response.json(content_type=None)

and you will see:
403 Forbidden
Error while making request to https://data.similarweb.com/api/v1/data?domain=httpbin.org: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

That is, the request failed and it doesn't contain any payload that could be parsed as JSON. The error actually comes from the JSON module, not from aiohttp.
The reasons for why this request failed with a 403 error depend on the web server. Perhaps they check the user agent or do some other verification.

The question was about "do some other verification" because requests.get with the same headers returns the correct json. Is it because the web server does not allow async calls?

@Neret The HTTP requests aren't async at all, that's just in your local code. You should print out all the request headers to see where the difference between the two methods is. The 403 error suggests a permission based issue.
